# How to add Transitions (Fade, dissolve etc ) in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, menu

I am trying to make a game for my semester project. I want to show a transition when user clicks on options button of my game menu or when user clicks on credits button. I want to show transition when one panel replaces another. Is it even possible? I am using java swing library.

Comment: Yep, as per @PM77-1, you haven't mentioned which GUI library you're using. Swing? AWT? SWT? Android? Other?

Comment: Note that if you're asking about Swing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/522444) of mine might help you. Run the code and test it to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a CardLayout to swap views (JPanels) in your GUI. To get a fade effect is not the most simple thing to do, but it can be done with a little work. I've done it successfully [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/522444) where I create a special class called SwappingImgPanel that extends JPanel, and that fades one image into another using a Swing Timer. Specifically, the program does this:

- The program adds all the swapping components to the CardLayout using JPanel.
- It also adds a single SwappingImgPanel, a JPanel created to draw two images, one of the component that is fading out, and one of the component that is fading in.
- When you swap components, you create images of the two components, the one currently visible, and the one that will next be visible.
- You send the images to the SwappingImgPanel instance
- You call `swap()` on the SwappingImgPanel instance.
- The SwappingImgPanel will then draw both images but uses a Swing Timer to change the Graphic object's composite value. This is what causes an image to be partially visible.
- When the SwappingImgPanel's Timer is done, a `done()` method is called which sets the SwappingImgPanel's State to State.DONE.
- The main GUI is listening to the SwappingImgPanel's state value, and when it achieves State.DONE, the main GUI shows the actual next component (and not an image of it).